# StackOverflowException in PowerShell when tab-completion/Intellisense is invoked

Tags: powershell, stack-overflow, assembly-resolution, powershell-ise

I'm writing a PowerShell module, in PowerShell, which has to redirect an assembly binding.
I had no problems using a `bindingRedirect` in `powershell_ise.exe.config` but I don't think this is acceptable for a module I want to distribute, so I looked for other ways and came across [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

I'm currently using this at the top of my `.psm1` file:

```
function Resolve-AssemblyRedirect {
    PARAM ([object]$sender, [System.ResolveEventArgs]$e)
    PROCESS {
        $requestedName = New-Object System.Reflection.AssemblyName $e.Name
        if ($requestedName.Name -eq "System.Net.Http.Primitives") {
            return [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$PSScriptRoot\Assemblies\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll")
        }

        return $null
    }
}

if (-not $Global:MODULE_LOADED) {
    [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.add_AssemblyResolve( { Resolve-AssemblyRedirect $Args[0] $Args[1] } )
    Set-Variable -Option Constant -Name MODULE_LOADED -Value $true -Scope Global
}
```

I can trigger the problem fairly reliably by using tab-completion/Intellisense in the ISE.  I have also seen it in the shell.  When I say fairly reliably, it's not always the same cmdlet that triggers it.  For example, in preparing this, I've triggered it with Get-ADUser [tab] and most recently, I typed get-por [tab], Intellisense displayed Get-GPOReport and then it hung.

If I comment-out the line beginning [AppDomain]::, and hammer tab-completion, I don't see a problem.

Before I go on, I want to point out that I've never had to debug anything in PowerShell, before, so there's been quite a bit of fumbling in the dark.  In order to debug, I added a `REG_SZ` to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug` with the name `Auto` and the value `1`, which is giving me the option to start VS 2012.  That is then showing me:

> System.StackOverflowException was unhandled

and when I look at the Call Stack I see:

```
mscorlib.dll!System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(string name, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) + 0x23c bytes    
System.Management.Automation.dll!System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategoryInfo.Ellipsize(System.Globalization.CultureInfo uiCultureInfo, string original) + 0x88 bytes 
System.Management.Automation.dll!System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeAsDelegateHelper(object dollarUnder, object dollarThis, object[] args) + 0x137 bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly assembly, string assemblyFullName) + 0xbc bytes  
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(string name, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Version version, bool throwOnFileNotFound, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark) + 0x3ab bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetSatelliteAssembly(System.Globalization.CultureInfo lookForCulture, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark) + 0xdd bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Resources.ResourceSet> localResourceSets, bool tryParents, bool createIfNotExists, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark) + 0xe2 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo requestedCulture, bool createIfNotExists, bool tryParents, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark) + 0x329 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, bool createIfNotExists, bool tryParents) + 0x23 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(string name, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) + 0x23c bytes    
Microsoft.PowerShell.Editor.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CompletionSession.Commit() + 0x285 bytes    
Microsoft.PowerShell.GPowerShell.dll!Microsoft.PowerShell.Host.ISE.PowerShellTab.TabComplete(Microsoft.PowerShell.Host.ISE.ISEEditor editor, bool forward) + 0x51c bytes    
Microsoft.PowerShell.GPowerShell.dll!Microsoft.PowerShell.Host.ISE.PowerShellTab.ProcessTab(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e, Microsoft.PowerShell.Host.ISE.PowerShellTab selectedPowerShellTab) + 0x167 bytes    
Microsoft.PowerShell.GPowerShell.dll!Microsoft.Windows.PowerShell.Gui.Internal.BeforeDefaultKeyProcessor.KeyDown(System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs args) + 0x4a bytes   
Microsoft.PowerShell.Editor.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.CallExtensionPoint(object errorSource, System.Action call) + 0x26 bytes 
Microsoft.PowerShell.Editor.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.KeyProcessorDispatcher.Dispatch<System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs>(System.Action<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.KeyProcessor,System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs> action, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs args) + 0x185 bytes 
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target) + 0x56 bytes  
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised) + 0x270 bytes  
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args) + 0x14e bytes 
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args) + 0x64 bytes   
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea() + 0x431 bytes   
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs input) + 0xab bytes 
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ReportInput(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.Windows.Input.InputMode mode, int timestamp, System.Windows.Input.RawKeyboardActions actions, int scanCode, bool isExtendedKey, bool isSystemKey, int virtualKey) + 0x124 bytes    
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ProcessKeyAction(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, ref bool handled) + 0x20e bytes  
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.CriticalTranslateAccelerator(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys modifiers) + 0x213 bytes  
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessage(object param) + 0x35e bytes  
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs) + 0x5e bytes 
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) + 0x47 bytes    
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs) + 0x2bc bytes 
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.Delegate method, object arg) + 0x42 bytes   
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessageThunk(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, ref bool handled) + 0x107 bytes 
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcherThread.RaiseThreadMessage(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg) + 0x4f bytes    
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.TranslateAndDispatchMessage(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg) + 0x2c bytes    
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) + 0x112 bytes 
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window) + 0x17a bytes    
Microsoft.PowerShell.GPowerShell.dll!Microsoft.Windows.PowerShell.Gui.Internal.Program.ShowMainWindow(System.Collections.Generic.List<string> filesToOpen, bool mta, bool noProfile, System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback loadedCallback) + 0x1a5 bytes  
[Native to Managed Transition]  
PowerShell_ISE.exe!Microsoft.Windows.PowerShell.GuiExe.Internal.GPowerShell.Main(string[] args) + 0x4d0 bytes
```

I've only included one repeat of the section between the lines:

```
mscorlib.dll!System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(string name, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) + 0x23c bytes
```

but that repeats a lot.

I've put this through the washer a few times and I don't always see the same results in the Call Stack.  For example, sometimes the repeating part looks like this:

```
mscorlib.dll!System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(string name, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) + 0x23c bytes    
System.Management.Automation.dll!System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategoryInfo.Ellipsize(System.Globalization.CultureInfo uiCultureInfo, string original) + 0x88 bytes 
System.Management.Automation.dll!System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeAsDelegateHelper(object dollarUnder, object dollarThis, object[] args) + 0x137 bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly assembly, string assemblyFullName) + 0xbc bytes  
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(string name, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Version version, bool throwOnFileNotFound, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark) + 0x3ab bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetSatelliteAssembly(System.Globalization.CultureInfo lookForCulture, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark) + 0xdd bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Resources.ResourceSet> localResourceSets, bool tryParents, bool createIfNotExists, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark) + 0xe2 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo requestedCulture, bool createIfNotExists, bool tryParents, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark) + 0x329 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, bool createIfNotExists, bool tryParents) + 0x23 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(string name, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) + 0x23c bytes
```

while the initial part before the repeat starts is often different.

From a bit of reading, it seems that LightweightFunction is probably my function Resolve-AssemblyRedirect.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I seem to be able to repro this by simply registering a resolver and calling Out-Gridview:    $OnAssemblyResolve = 
  [System.ResolveEventHandler] {
    param($sender, $resolveEventArgs)
          return null;
        }
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.add_AssemblyResolve($OnAssemblyResolve); 1..10 | out-gridview

Comment: It seems with PowerShell (not PowerShell ISE), the StackOverflowException does not happen after adding a AssemblyResolve event handler.

Answer (score 3):

Without digging into the AppDomain assembly resolution stuff, I can tell that you that most likely there is a non-terminating loop in the code path represented by the repeating lines in the stack walk. Each time the code goes through the loop it eats up more stack until all the stack's been used and you get the exception with the same name as this web site.

My guess is that the change you made to the .config file causes .NET to behave badly.

Using reflector I can see the infinite loop. InvokeAsDelegateHelper calls GetContextFromTLS. GetContextFromTLS calls GetExecutionContextFromTLS. GetExecutionContextFromTLS returns null if the DefaultRunspace is null. When GetContextFromTLS gets a null back from GetExecutionContextFromTLS (among other things) it calls  ErrorCategory.Ellipsize. Ellipsize reads the property ErrorPackage.Ellipsize. The ErrorPackage.Ellipsize accessor method calls ResourceManager.GetString, which restarts the loop

So it looks like the bad behavior comes from having a null DefaultRunspace. I'm not sure how that would happen if you are just using Powershell.exe to run your script. But if you are invoking Powershell from, say, C#, then you probably have a bug in your code that invokes Powershell. Either way it would probably be helpful to look on MSDN at the documentation regarding launching Powershell from a program.

HTH

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using the PowerShell ISE.  I'm going to copy a clean .config file and see if I can recreate it.

Comment: It's not the .config file.  I've recreated the problem on another machine with an unadulterated .config file.

Comment: The key factor is DefaultRunspace is null. Maybe the script is running on a thread that is not setup to run Powershell. "TLS" means thread local storage. You could add a bit of logic to the script to output what thread it's running on (`[threading.thread]::CurrentThread`) and see if it's the same thread that is executing Powershell. Or try running PS with -STA command line option. Good luck

Comment: I added that command into the module's .psm1 file and I ran it directly in the console pane of the ISE.  They gave the same ManagedThreadId.  In summary, it's a Normal priority, STA apartment state thread, called 'Pipeline Execution Thread'.

Comment: I've also run [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace]::DefaultRunspace in the module's .psm1 file and directly in the ISE's console pane.  It's not null, there.  They have the same InstanceId.

Comment: @Simon If you want to look into the logic behind the stack overflow you can use Reflector or a number of open source alternatives. I think the third paragraph in my answer will guide you through the logic.

Comment: Have done so using Reflector Pro.  Thanks for the guidance.  Reflector couldn't show me the values of a lot of the variables but the path followed did suggest the context was null.

Comment: :-) I've +1'd it, since you've given me a start but I can't mark it as answered because I've still got the problem.

Comment: @Xpw I had a very similar repeating stack pattern.  After staring at it awhile, the significance of TLS sank in - I was calling a method that started a `Task` and then caused some assemblies to be loaded.  I rewrote the handler in C#, wrapped it in `Add-Type` and everybody was happy after that.

Answer (score 0):

$e.Name contains not only the assembly name, but also version info, etc. like

```
System.IO.Abstractions, Version=2.1.0.178, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96bf224d23c43e59
```

so your name comparison and dll loading would never work.
I've encountered the same problem yesterday, it turns out that a bug in name comparison and resolving failed for some assemblies like System.Management.Automation.resources.dll in some cases, which caused resolving retried again and again, and finally crashed for stack overflow.

besides, in my case, put add_assemblyResolve function call before calling add-type could also cause the same problem.